# How to access e-mail headers

Tags: google-chrome-extension, email-headers

I'm developing an extension that, as part of its processing, needs to access the user's message headers. Since they aren't contained in the HTML, a call is made to a servlet running in our server, which is hosted by Amazon Web Services, that connects to the Gmail IMAP server using the user's credentials. However, the first time the user runs the extension, Google sends a warning email to the user asking if it's OK to let the connection happen and blocks the connection until the user OKs it.
Is there any way for the user to OK the connection in advance and if not, how can else I get at the headers?

Comment: 1) What kind of credentials are you talking about? 2) Does it happen on every connection attempt, or once per user?

Comment: 1. IMAP login credentials (e-mail address and password). 2. Only the first time.